# генерация sitemap.xml с большим количеством данных

Tags: php

У меня есть скрипт, который генерирует файл sitemap.xml .  Из-за большого количества данных гео, не хватает оперативки на выполнение (даже на локалке).  В сумме получается больше 70тыс. записей должно генерироваться.
Подскажите, каким образом можно упростить(облегчить) генерацию: как-то разбивать на части или код переделать ?

```html
foreach($obj_geoData->selectAllCountry() as $all_country){// 1 страна - Россия

 foreach($obj_geoData->selectRegion($all_country['country_id']) as $all_region){// порядка 70 регионов России

  foreach($obj_geoData->selectCity($all_region['region_id']) as $all_city){// больше тысячи городов России
  
   $urls[]=array("loc"=>$url_site."/".$all_country['translit']."/".$all_region['translit']."/".$all_city['translit']."/alladv/","changefreq"=>"daily","priority"=>0.8);


   $mas_top_category = $obj_doska_cache_category->get_mas_data(0,false,false);

   foreach ($mas_top_category as $one_top_category)
     {
      
      $url_top_category = $url_site."/".$all_country['translit']."/".$all_region['translit']."/".$all_city['translit']."/alladv/".$one_top_category["united_name_url"]."/";
      $urls[]=array("loc"=>$url_top_category,"changefreq"=>"daily","priority"=>0.8);
      forming_url_sitemap_nested_category_all_country($one_top_category["id_category"],$url_top_category);
     }
    
   }

 }
}
```

Comment: Это типа google sitmap файл?

Comment: А обязательно хранить кучу данных в переменной? Не лучше ли их сразу на вывод? Или какой нибудь временный файл?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, то нажмите на галочку слева от ответа, который вам помог.

Answer (score 2):

Вы можете разбить свой sitemap на несколько файлов, создать индекс файл и пользоваться им.

Вот тут можно почитать про структуру индекса.
https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/75712?rd=1

В вашем случае, видимо, имеет смысл разбить на порции, скажем, по 5 тысяч адресов в каждом файле.
Ну и во время генерации оперативка будет освобождаться каждый раз как Вы закрыли один файл... и начали новый...

Answer (score 1):

Для больших файлов записи / чтения  - нужно писать / читать последовательно через while.